# iPhone hide Navigation Bar only on first page

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, hide

I have the code below that hides and shows the navigational bar.  It is hidden when the first view loads and then hidden when the "children" get called.  Trouble is that I cannot find the event/action to trigger it to hide again when they get back to the root view....

I have a "test" button on the root page that manually does the action but it is not pretty and I want it to be automatic.

```
-(void)hideBar 
{
    self.navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
-(void)showBar 
{       
    self.navController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1063, accepted):

The nicest solution I have found is to do the following in the **first view controller**.

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

This will cause the navigation bar to animate in from the left (together with the next view) when you push the next `UIViewController` on the stack, and animate away to the left (together with the old view), when you press the back button on the `UINavigationBar`.

Please note also that these are not delegate methods, you are overriding `UIViewController`'s implementation of these methods, and according to the documentation you **must call the super's implementation somewhere in your implementation**.

Comment: This totally rocks!  I had been struggling with this for at least a day.  Thanks!!!

Comment: I thought the view frame would have change but it does until viewDidAppear: :( So if you need the exact frame after hiding the navigationBar, this is not the solution.

Comment: My second view controller's top bar is also hidden :(

Comment: nice but undefined behaviour for multiple VCs that may or may not have the navbar hidden....

Comment: In iOS 7, using an opaque navigation bar, I am having all of my views "pushed" down below the screen. I'm guessing I should be resizing my views at the same time, but not sure exactly what method to call or where to call it. Any help?

Comment: Does anyone know why it seems that you can only show/hide the navbar in the rootVC?

Comment: **WARNING:** This creates a very bad bug when doing a fast backswipe. Assume A (no navbar) and B (with navbar) pushed onto the stack. When on view B and doing a fast backswipe, but release early enough to stay on B, the navbar still gets hidden. Now there is no way to go back anymore. This is due to `animated=YES`. I know it looks ugly with `animated=NO`, but it seems when the animation for hiding the navbar is not yet finished, then the animation for showing it again is ignored. No solution yet.

Comment: In Swift:
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
super.viewWillAppear(true)
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
super.viewWillDisappear(true)
}

Comment: Yes, I use the navigationcontroller delegate. When backswiping it is not so nice though as only when the backswipe is finished, the navigation bar state can be adapted, as it is unknown if the backswipe will be aborted or not.

Comment: Question was answered in 2010 and helps me at the end of 2015! Thank you.

Comment: Now that's what I call a legendary answer. Superb trick mate. Even working after decades...Implemented the same in swift, working flawlessly. +1 for your answer @Alan Rogers

Comment: Still holding up in 2016!

Comment: Please update your answer and put the code after the call to super

Comment: As this is the accepted and most voted answer, you should consider to edit the solution to include another (and actually correct) fix: check out @Chad M answer.

Answer (score 78):

Another approach I found is to set a delegate for the `NavigationController`:

```
navigationController.delegate = self;
```

and use `setNavigationBarHidden` in `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                    animated:(BOOL)animated 
{   
    // Hide the nav bar if going home.
    BOOL hide = viewController != homeViewController;
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:hide animated:animated];
}
```

Easy way to customize the behavior for each `ViewController` all in one place.

Comment: When will this get called?

Comment: Perfect solution.  This should be the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Perfect answer. It also works in case we cannot override viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods on the first view controller.

Comment: Awesome. The chosen answer works ok, however only in simple apps. This answer works when nav bar is in a tab controller and pushes / presents various VCs in various ways.

Comment: This is the best answer. The top answer may occur a bug as @[fabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354018/fabb)'s description.

Comment: This is a very nice solution for MoreNavigationController of the UITabBarController. Should be the accepted answer really.

Comment: Thanks! you are a hero!

Comment: @Borzh Actually this solution has a bug. Try to start pop view controller by gesture and then interrupt gesture. You will see that code has been executed for vc under the top vc

Answer (score 19):

One slight tweak I had to make on the other answers is to only unhide the bar in viewWillDisappear if the reason it is disappearing is due to a navigation item being pushed on it. This is because the view can disappear for other reasons.

So I only unhide the bar if this view is no longer the topmost view:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.navigationController.topViewController != self)
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    }

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: +1, you _usually_ don't want to show the navigation bar when pushing a modal dialog.

Answer (score 18):

I would put the code in the **viewWillAppear** delegate on each view being shown:

Like this where you need to hide it:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [yourObject hideBar];
}
```

Like this where you need to show it:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [yourObject showBar];
}
```

Comment: Lee, if this fixed your problem, mark Pablo's as the "solution" answer.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the navigation bar "pops" out and into view as you navigate from one view to the next. Is it possible just to have the navigation bar not there on the first view, and when the second view slides into place, it has the nav bar, without any popping?

Comment: @henning

To make the NavBar slide in/out as you would expect, you need to use setNavigationBarHidden:animated:. See Alan Rogers' answer below (which should really be marked as the "solution").

Comment: This answer is slightly wrong (viewWill/DidAppear) should be calling super.  Also See my answer below for a solution where you don't need to add it to EVERY view controller.

Answer (score 15):

The currently accepted answer does not match the intended behavior described in the question. The question asks for the navigation bar to be hidden on the root view controller, but visible everywhere else, but the accepted answer hides the navigation bar on a particular view controller. What happens when another instance of the first view controller is pushed onto the stack? It will hide the navigation bar even though we are not looking at the root view controller.

Instead, @Chad M.'s [strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6418606/2434476) of using the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` is a good one, and here is a more complete solution. Steps:

1. Subclass `UINavigationController`
2. Implement the `-navigationController:willShowViewController:animated` method to show or hide the navigation bar based on whether it is showing the root view controller
3. Override the initialization methods to set the UINavigationController subclass as its own delegate

Complete code for this solution can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/hspinks/d2167ff08341720662bf). Here's the `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated` implementation:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    /* Hide navigation bar if root controller */
    if ([viewController isEqual:[self.viewControllers firstObject]]) {
        [self setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    } else {
        [self setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a more appropriate answer than the accepted one

Answer (score 14):

in Swift 3:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if (navigationController?.topViewController != self) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    }
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Comment: could you explain why you check for != self?

Comment: @Kitson, check the user486646' answer:

_One slight tweak I had to make on the other answers is to only unhide the bar in viewWillDisappear if the reason it is disappearing is due to a navigation item being pushed on it. This is because the view can disappear for other reasons.

So I only unhide the bar if this view is no longer the topmost view_

Comment: It seems that if you use the `navcontroller.navagationBarHidden` it will break the entire navigation controller (no swiping back and forth). To get it to work I used `navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden` instead. Swiping still works and it doesn't leave empty space because it seems to be inside a stackview or something

Answer (score 9):

Give my credit to @chad-m 's answer.

Here is the Swift version:

1. Create a new file `MyNavigationController.swift`

---

```
import UIKit

class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self.viewControllers.first {
            self.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
        } else {
            self.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
        }
    }

}
```

2. Set your UINavigationController's class in StoryBoard to MyNavigationController
   [image: MyNavigationController]
   **That's it!**

Difference between chad-m's answer and mine:

1. Inherit from UINavigationController, so you won't pollute your rootViewController.
2. use `self.viewControllers.first` rather than `homeViewController`, so you won't do this 100 times for your 100 UINavigationControllers in 1 StoryBoard.

Comment: Think this is the cleanest answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

After multiple trials here is how I got it working for what I wanted. 
This is what I was trying. 
- I have a view with a image. and I wanted to have the image go full screen. 
- I have a navigation controller with a tabBar too. So i need to hide that too. 
- Also, my main requirement was not just hiding, but having a fading effect too while showing and hiding.

This is how I got it working.

Step 1 - I have a image and user taps on that image once. I capture that gesture and push it into the new `imageViewController`, its in the `imageViewController`, I want to have full screen image.

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {  
NSLog(@"Single tap");
ImageViewController *imageViewController =
[[ImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageViewController" bundle:nil];

godImageViewController.imgName  = // pass the image.
godImageViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;// This is important to note. 

[self.navigationController pushViewController:godImageViewController animated:YES];
// If I remove the line below, then I get this error. [CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance . 
// [godImageViewController release];
}
```

Step 2 - All these steps below are in the ImageViewController

Step 2.1 - In ViewDidLoad, show the navBar

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Step 2.2 - In `viewDidAppear`, set up a timer task with delay ( I have it set for 1 sec delay). And after the delay, add fading effect. I am using alpha to use fading.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");

myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self     selector:@selector(fadeScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)fadeScreen
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; // begins animation block
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.95];        // sets animation duration
self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0;       // Fades the alpha channel of   this view to "0.0" over the animationDuration of "0.75" seconds
[UIView commitAnimations];   // commits the animation block.  This Block is done.
}
```

step 2.3 - Under `viewWillAppear`, add singleTap gesture to the image and make the navBar translucent.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.imgName ofType:@"png"];

UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

self.imgView.image = theImage;

// add tap gestures 
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];  
[self.imgView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];  
[singleTap release];  

// to make the image go full screen
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=YES;
}

- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{ 
 NSLog(@"Handle Single tap");
 [self finishedFading];
  // fade again. You can choose to skip this can add a bool, if you want to fade again when user taps again. 
 myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self  selector:@selector(fadeScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
 }
```

Step 3 - Finally in `viewWillDisappear`, make sure to put all the stuff back

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear: (BOOL)animated 
{ 
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO; 
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;

if (self.navigationController.topViewController != self)
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}

[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone still having trouble with the **fast backswipe cancelled bug** as @fabb commented in the accepted answer.

I manage to fix this by overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, in addition to `viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear` as shown below:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

//*** This is required to fix navigation bar forever disappear on fast backswipe bug.
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```

In my case, I notice that it is because the root view controller (where nav is hidden) and the pushed view controller (nav is shown) **has different status bar styles** (e.g. dark and light). The moment you start the backswipe to pop the view controller, there will be additional status bar colour animation. If you release your finger in order to cancel the interactive pop, **while the status bar animation is not finished**, the navigation bar is forever gone!

However, this bug doesn't occur if status bar styles of both view controllers are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to hide the navigation bar completely in the controller, a much cleaner solution is to, in the root controller, have something like:

```
@implementation MainViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
    //...extra code on view load  
}
```

When you push a child view in the controller, the Navigation Bar will remain hidden; if you want to display it just in the child, you'll add the code for displaying `it(self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;)` in the `viewWillAppear` callback, and similarly the code for hiding it on `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest implementation may be to just have each view controller specify whether its navigation bar is hidden or not in its `viewWillAppear:animated:` method. The same approach works well for hiding/showing the toolbar as well:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES/NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Actually, my suggestion only makes sense for the toolbar, since hiding the navigation bar without a matching call to show it would leave users unable to navigate back from the current view.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding navigation bar only on first page can be achieved through storyboard as well. On storyboard, goto *Navigation Controller Scene->Navigation Bar*. And select '*Hidden*' property from the *Attributes inspector*. This will hide navigation bar starting from first viewcontroller until its made visible for the required viewcontroller.

Navigation bar can be set back to visible in  ViewController's ViewWillAppear callback.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];                                                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4:**

In the view controller you want to hide the navigation bar from.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By implement this code in your ViewController you can get this effect
 Actually the trick is , hide the navigationBar when that Controller is launched

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

and unhide the navigation bar when user leave that page  do this is viewWillDisappear

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```