# how to create a menu based ios application in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have no idea how to set up a menu based project in xcode 4.2.

Basically, the menu has 4 buttons in it each go to their own Navigation Controlled tableviews, but I'm not sure where to start with xcode 4.2.

In my previous application I have a main window that has the navigation controller in that, then there is a root view which sets up the 4 buttons and from there the tableview view controllers just get loaded into the navigation controller.

With xcode 4.2 I cannot seem to set the delegate of the main window, so I cannot figure this out.

So I am hoping someone understands what I am trying to do and can help me out or send me a example or tutorial or something. Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I setup my navigation controller and root view in the AppDelegate file. From there you can just add the buttons and so on just as before. If you mean to do it with the storyboard, it will be much easier. Let me know if I misunderstood the question though:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self managedObjectModel];
    [self managedObjectContext];

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    RootViewController *controller = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

    [self.window setRootViewController:navigation];
    [controller release];
    [navigation release];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: okay I am pretty sure I get this, I'm going to try it out on a test app now.. However what do you think of the storyboard facilities? are they worth the hassle of learning them etc? are they very restrictive for building navigation based apps?.. I think I need to do more reading on them..

Comment: I found that they were amazing in the power they allowed developers while being very, very easy to use! The only catch is that as development gets more complex, doing it programmatically has many benefits as well. It really comes down to what you are designing. Research is definitely something that should be done before choosing either path.

Comment: yea cool thats what I thought.. man xcode 4.2 has thrown me abit of a curve ball still having issues trying to figure out how to make this menu to navcontroller. pain in the butt. thanks for your help however.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be fine with one UINavigationController.  In your view with the 4 menu buttons just hide the UINavigationController.

[Hide / Show UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845583/iphone-hide-navigation-bar-only-on-first-page)