# Multiple view for same tab bar item

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

i'm sorry for my english.
I'm trying to develop my first app and i have a tab bar controller connected to some view controller. In one of these i have some images and when i click on image a UITapGestureRecognizer navigate to navigation controller like in the storyboard in this link:

http://www.manuelragazzini.it/storyboard_navigation.png

That's works but there is a problem. In navigation controller view there isn't the tab bar. I want to keep the tab bar controller also in the "navigation controller view". There is a way to keep on the tab bar?

If is it possible i want keep the first view controller without navigation controller and only when a user tap on image the navigation controller appear with tab bar in the new view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your segue between your map view and your navigation controller is a Modal Segue, so it's normal that you don't see anymore your tabbar. I think you should use a navigation controller for your first screen and hide what you don't want to use, it's the easier way to do what you want.

EDIT : your storyboard should looks like this :

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok for modal segues but i need to show in the first view a set of images and when i tap one of these i would see a view totally different (with map, labels and other things). Can i implement all of these things in only one view? I'm sorry if my question are stupid but these are my first experiences.

Comment: Not in a single view no, keep your views like they are, remove your navigation controller and put a new one between your tab bar controller and your map view (select your view which contents you map, editor menu > embed in > navigation controller). If you don't want to see the navigation bar on your first screen you can hide it : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2406167/2108210.

Answer (score 0):

Your misunderstanding how the UINavigation works. When you move to a new view controller the last one is pushed down on the stack and the new one is made visible. If you want to show a new controller with a tab bar, then add the tab bar to your new controller too. Be sure to read this thoroughly

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok, the UINavigation push down the old view. So, which type of segue or connection do you suggest for navigate to the new view and keep the tab bar? thanks a lot.