# Navigating From UITableViewController to a Initial ViewController in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

How to go back from a Table View Controller using navigation controller to a View Controller without navigation controller? Here is my Storyboard.

Comment: My ViewController is the Initial View Controller

Comment: show ur storyboard screen shot

Comment: How did you get from MyViewController to the table view controller in the first place?

Comment: [link](http://www.ornilosantiago.com/ios/how-to-back-viewController.jpg)

Comment: u r allocating the Navigation controller in wrong, embed the navigation controller with main view controller

Comment: I did from My Main.storyboard using (push), dragging the button to the TableViewController

Comment: But I don't want to show the Navigation Controller on the first ViewController

Comment: That's not a push, it's a show (which acts like a push if you are embedded in a navigation controller, and like a modal if you're not). You should use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: to go back (or you could use an unwind segue).

Comment: Sorry, I meant (Show). I figured out how to work, I add a navigation controller to my initiated ViewController and removed the another one that I did for my TableViewController. My problem now is, how to hide the Navigation Controller from my first View Controller?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845583/iphone-hide-navigation-bar-only-on-first-page ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call 'pop' on the navigation controller

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```