# How to hide UINavigationBar from a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view controller  that is embedded in a UINavigationController,how can I hide the UINavigationBar? I want the navigation functionality but I don't want that bar in the top..

tnx

Comment: Have you looked at the API docs for `UINavigationController`? There are methods to show/hide the navigation bar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

to get it back, just call:

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];`

source: [How to hide the UINavigationBar for my first view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845583/iphone-hide-navigation-bar-only-on-first-page)

Answer (score 0):

To hide navigationBar you can use below code

```
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

To Unhide navigationBar you can use below code

```
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

By implement this code in your ViewController you can hide specific viewController
 Actually the trick is , hide the navigationBar when that Controller is launched

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

and unhide the navigation bar when user leave that page do this is viewWillDisappear

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```