# Set NavigationBar for Destination ViewController Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a ViewController called `SourceViewController` that is embedded in a NavigationController.

`SourceViewController` segues to `DestinationViewController` upon `UITableViewCell` selection.

I want to hide the navigation bar on `SourceViewController`, but display it on `DestinationViewController` in order to show the Back button.

So, in `SourceViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
}
```

And in `DestinationViewController`: 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false
}
```

However, when I tap "Back" in `DestinationViewController` to return to `SourceViewController`, the navigationBar reappears in `SourceViewController`

The next 'obvious' step would be to set `navigationBar.hidden = false` in `viewDidAppear` in `SourceViewController`, however this smells for many reasons: mainly DRYness but also when returning to `SourceViewController`, there is a delay in hiding the `navigationBar`, and it is visible for a split second.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please check answer of this question ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845583/iphone-hide-navigation-bar-only-on-first-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work, hiding the navigation bar. before appearing/disappearing the view.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}


override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check ViewController lifecycle [Looking to understand the iOS UIViewController lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle) .
When you start the program viewDidLoad is called and everything is ok, but when you go back from detailController, viewDidLoad is not called, just change this line (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true) in viewWillApear and everything must be ok.