# Hiding the navigation and status bars for only one UIViewController inside a UINavigationController stack

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboardsegue

I want one of my pushed viewControllers in a navigation controller stack to be "full screen" - no navigation bar and no status bar. 
I have this code that hides and shows the navigation bar in one of the view controllers of navigation controller (I want it to be pushed on full screen):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated:animated)   
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:animated) 
}
```

In the same viewController I'm also hiding the status bar with this:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

It is hiding and showing as expected but the problem is that I get a black stripe on the transition when pushing this view controller and back from it (see images).

Push to this controller:
[Push to this controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M4Qo.png)

And back from this controller (back button):

[Back from this controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxWY7.png)

It appears this is happening because of the prefersStatusBarHidden function Removing this solves the issue.

The code for show/hide the nav bar is taken from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2406167/4207465

and based on apple developer library: 
"Showing and Hiding the Navigation Bar -
When a navigation bar is used in conjunction with a navigation controller, you always use the setNavigationBarHidden:animated: method of UINavigationController to show and hide the navigation bar..."

Not sure why it's happening,
Thanks for the help!

Comment: It appears this is happening because of the prefersStatusBarHidden Removing this solves the issue, investigating why..

Answer (score 1):

@Boaz Frenkel

There is one solution to fix the black strip during hide and show of navigation bar with or without status bar.

**ViewController A : Fullscreen View**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .Fade)
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

**ViewController B : With NavigationBar and status bar**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: .None)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to hide navigation bar in viewDidAppear. Now you're hidding bar before showing controller.

```
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super. viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated:    animated)
}
```