# Deinit Two ViewController at the same time in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two `UIViewController`. First one is a welcome screen and second one is a login screen (which is inside a navigation Controller). Users can go back to welcome screen from login screen with a back button so login screen opens with `self.present(LoginViewController(),animated: false)` and after Login Screen, final `UIViewController` opens with `appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = FinalViewController()`.

My problem is that neither `LoginViewController` or `WelcomeViewController` deinit at this scenario. However, If I;

- Open `FinalViewController` (via changing RootViewController) directly from `WelcomeViewController`, without showing `LoginViewController`.
- Open `LoginViewController` without showing `WelcomeViewController` then open `FinalViewController` (again changing RootViewController)

Controllers deinited. So I don't think any of viewcontroller has a retain cycle vs..

I want to deinit both login and welcome screens after open final controller.

**EDIT:** I found that putting it inside NavigationController blocks the deniting.

**EDIT2:**  If I call `self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)` before changing rootViewController. All controllers seems to be deinited but I'm not sure If It will be a better answer.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use this hierarchy:

```
-UIWindow
-----UIWindow.RootViewController
----------UINavigationController
---------------WelcomeScreen
---------------LoginScreen (Push without animation)
```

On Login Success:

```
-UIWindow
-----UIWindow.RootViewController
----------UINavigationController
---------------FinalViewController
```

Hide navigation bar and use `animated` property as per need.

**EDIT**

A part from [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present):

> **viewControllerToPresent**
>
> The view controller to display *over the current view controller*’s content.

So reference of the parent controller can be access from presented controller, hence both VCs can access each other. e.g., `self.presentedViewController`. In order to remove it, one must dismiss controller. So presented controller will release the reference of presenter controller.

Comment: Because Welcome screen doesn't have a navigation bar.

Comment: and you are bound to keep it outside navigation controller?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand?

Comment: Why Welcome screen is not inside navigation controller? can you move welcome screen in navigation controller?

Comment: Because Welcome screen doesn't have a navigation bar. As you say, I can put it inside navigation controller and hide navigation bar but as I read in this post, It may cause some problems while swiping etc.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845583/iphone-hide-navigation-bar-only-on-first-page

Comment: By the way my final controller is a complicated one which is a UITabberController which has 5 UIViewControllers inside UINavigationController

Comment: "Users can go back to welcome screen from login screen with a back button so login screen opens with..." Is this custom back button or navigation bar back button ?