# How to find out when the method of an object has been called?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `UIViewController` object.
I would like to know when the `viewDidLoad` method has been called.

I understand that I can override this method in the subclass and find out when it is called.

Is there another to know when the `viewDidLoad` method is called?

Edit-

I have several view controllers that are pushed onto an `UINavigationController`.
Some of these view controllers hide the navigation bars. This can be done using the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2406167).

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

At the present, I have repeated this code in a number of view controllers.

I am trying to remove the repetition of code.

One way to do this would be create a super class that contains this code and have the view controllers that hide the navigation bar subclass this super class. However, some of the view controllers that hide the navigation bar descend from `UITableViewController` and `UICollectionViewController`.

I am trying to create a class that will observe when the `viewWillAppear(_:)` and `viewWillDisappear(_:)` is called on view controller and then call the method to hide and show navigation bar.

Comment: Did you try using [Breakpoints](https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/xcode-debugging-with-breakpoints-for-beginners-5b0d0a39d711)?

Comment: otherwise, there is a great thread [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5562938/1040347) about UIViewController's lifecycle

Comment: As you've also said, you can override the method, and then use a breakpoint to check when is it called.

Comment: Why do you need to know that? Answers might be different then.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov Breakpoints cannot be used because this is not used for debugging but rather for performing action when the program is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be implemented in old faithful Objective-C via [Method Swizzling](https://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/).

Go in your Xcode:

1. Create a New File -> Objective-C with Filename "Lifecycle" and File Type
   "Category" and Class "UIViewController"
2. Xcode will offer to create the [Bridging Header](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-create-an-objective-c-bridging-header-to-use-code-in-swift) file if such does not exist.
3. Put inside your Bridging Header newly created file: `#import "UIViewController+Lifecycle.h"`
4. Your `UIViewController+Lifecycle.h` should look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (Lifecycle)

+ (void)setViewControllerSwizzlingActive:(BOOL)wantedState;

@end
```

5. Your `UIViewController+Lifecycle.m` should look like this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import "UIViewController+Lifecycle.h"

@implementation UIViewController (Lifecycle)

+ (void)setViewControllerSwizzlingActive:(BOOL)wantedState
{
    static BOOL isWorkaroundActive = NO;
    if (isWorkaroundActive != wantedState)
    {
        [self exchangeViewWillAppearMethod];
        [self exchangeViewWillDisappearMethod];
        isWorkaroundActive = wantedState;
    }
}

+ (void)exchangeViewWillAppearMethod
{
    Method original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(viewWillAppear:));
    Method fake = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(fakeViewWillAppear:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, fake);
}

+ (void)exchangeViewWillDisappearMethod
{
    Method original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(viewWillDisappear:));
    Method fake = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(fakeViewWillDisappear:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, fake);
}

- (void)fakeViewWillAppear:(BOOL *)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    return [self fakeViewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)fakeViewWillDisappear:(BOOL *)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    return [self fakeViewWillDisappear:animated];
}

@end
```

6. Then, activate your swizzling, say in `AppDelegate's` didFinishLaunching method like: `ViewController.setViewControllerSwizzlingActive(true)`

If you want Swift version - this would be a task for you.