# iOS 13: threading violation: expected the main thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, uinavigationbar, ios13

The app is being crashed when trying to hide the navigation bar for a viewcontroller only for **iOS 13** users.

- I got the crash on Crashlytics of Fabric which titled as below,

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>
> threading violation: expected the main thread

- The app is being crashed on this line of viewWillAppear method,

```
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

- To hide the navigation bar on the viewWillAppear method of UIViewController, I am using below code,

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
```

- To show the navigation bar on the viewWillDisappear method of UIViewController, I am using below code,

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }
```

Comment: Are you doing this procedure in a thread different from the Main one?

Comment: I think this way it the safe way to help you hide navigation https://stackoverflow.com/a/6418606/2454521

Comment: @MattiaRighetti, I am not doing this procedure in any thread.

Comment: @QuangDam Thanks for the solution, but Will this solution resolve the crash?

Comment: @Nikunj, you should scroll up the page I sent you, you will see a lot of answers about the problem. I think it can be useful

Comment: Are you instantiating that viewController in a background thread? `threading violation: expected the main thread` is the key to your crash.

Comment: @Starsky I am not instantiating that viewController in a background thread.

Comment: @QuangDam again I got crashes same way after applying the solution, but it is a few as compared to the previous crash, please help if you have any solution regarding 'expected the main thread'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58499124 @QuangDam please checkout this issue, which I have got after applying the solution

Answer (score 13):

do following action

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
  }
```

Comment: nice excelent my friend

Comment: @karim for work with UI always have to do actions into the main thread, and for example: 

```java
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```
 is an action that related to the view.