# iOS 13: @objc VC.navigationController(_:willShow:animated:) : threading violation: expected the main thread

Tags: ios, swift, crash, uinavigationbar, ios13

I got the crash on Crashlytics of Fabric only for iOS 13 users when the NavigationBar of the particular ViewController is being hidden.

I tried by hiding the NavigationBar for particular ViewController by using NavigationController's delegate method

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    let hide = (viewController is MyVC)
    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(hide, animated: animated)
}
```

But it also generating the crash on crashlytics called

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

threading violation: expected the main thread
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for the above issue,

I used Xcode 10.2.1 to upload the build of the app, and I didn't get any crashes now.

Comment: Hi Nikunj, can you pls share your answer

Answer (score 0):

Hide it on main thread

```
Dispatch.main.async {
    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(hide, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this helped

Comment: If I try to add it in main thread, then it will be hidden with a blink

Comment: then hide it without animation

Comment: and why you are not setting it in MyVC?

Comment: I used to add it in MyVC, but similar crash generated

Comment: So One of my friend suggested me to do this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335061/ios-13-threading-violation-expected-the-main-thread

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden` from a background Thread?

Try:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
     self?.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(hide, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: I don't call navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden from a background Thread.

Comment: so you say that `threading violation: expected the main thread` this error is lying?

Comment: But I just want to find why is this happening?