# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'threading violation: expected the main thread'

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, ios13

My app is consuming a third party library and there is crash that happens on certain device such as iOS 13.3

Tried calling the method on main thread

> Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread:
>   -[UIApplication statusBarOrientation] PID: 1496, TID: 390696, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS:
>   0
>
> 2020-01-28 12:31:47.733875+0000 My BT Gotham[1496:390696] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'threading violation:
>   expected the main thread'

Tried calling the method on background thread

Here is the errror

> - Assertion failure in -[FBSSerialQueue assertOnQueue], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/FrontBoardServices/FrontBoard-626.4.1/FrontBoardServices/FBSSerialQueue.m:98
>     2020-01-28 17:23:47.972336+0000 My BT Gotham[1773:459656] ***
>     Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>     'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'threading violation:
>     expected the main thread'

FYI:
I always the API method on background thread and it works fine in most of the devices the issue that I quoted above works only in some devices.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    [LibObj model_Method:self];
});
```

Comment: error says " 'threading violation: expected the main thread'", did u try calling it on main thread?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 13: threading violation: expected the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335061/ios-13-threading-violation-expected-the-main-thread)

Comment: @TejaNandamuri  - I tried calling on main thread i'm getting crash again uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'threading violation: expected the main thread'

Comment: If you really call it on the main thread maybe the bug is on the third party library. In that case I don't think there is much we can do with just this info

Answer (score 0):

As it appears, you are calling UI methods from the background... It should be something like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  // use your method...
}
```

But if your third-party lib is already doing the DispatchQueue.main call behind the scenes, is possible that when you do your async call it gets messed up...

Comment: I tried calling the method on main thread in async fashion on Objective C. dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    
});

Comment: But thing to note is it's working in all the devices and crashes in few devices when I call in background thread.

Comment: Which devices? arm64e only? ios 13 only? How consistent is the crash? It has to have a pattern...

Comment: the device that I'm testing is iphone 6s

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{     ///Write your code Here. Mostly UI update should be writen here. In my case i am calling method of common controller like this. myclass myMethod:self] });